# Skrollr not working in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parallax, skrollr

I've included the gem and ran bundle which includes all the files in the gem lib perfectly fine.

application.js looks as such:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require skrollr
//= require skrollr.stylesheets
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require_tree .
```

I've included this in the bottom of application.html.erb before the end of the body tag and also tried including in individual view as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    skroller.init();
  });
</script>
```

and for calling this in the view I used the example provided by skrollr:

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);" data-500="background- color:rgb(0,0,255);">
    WOOOT
</div>
```

but to my dismay I have not seen any effects. What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Have you checked your development and see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    skrollr.init(); # skroller changed to skrollr
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I had completely overlooked that, It's been a very long day and thought i had double checked the spelling!